# Google Index returns not safe results on my website

Tags: indexing, robots.txt

I have a website Joomla based, and some persons start saying that my website were redirecting to "not safe contents" when searched on google or bing, so I made all the checks necessary and found that I had about 100 files .htacess with redirects to that non safe results.

I did this:

Point 1.
I made a backup of the joomla installation and the databases to the computer.
Point 2.
I removed these databases, and the public_html site itself
Point 3.
When I searched google, I still had the same problem, so I went to: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch (where basically a reindexing of the platform will be done, and the way the bot is changed View the site);
Point 4.
Check the entire installation locally, especially Modules and Theme folders always in index.php where there probably might be a link with the text captcha, look for the htaccess in your installations and delete everything.

At first It solved but now, even with robots.txt It redirects to that non safe content.

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /index.html 
Allow: /style.css
Disallow: /
```

At the moment, as you can see it should be only allowed to access those two files.

How can I avoid google from index my website to that non-safe content, after fetching the site on webmasters tools?

Thanks

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g05eib -> This was supposed to be the result however it redirects to other places

Answer (score 0):

Solved, usually they re-index in about 2 or 3 hours, this time it took a little more time (12hours).

Advice:  before you re-upload the platforms, do a advance check to mitigate all the problems.